# contains() algorithm for std::vector

Tags: c++

I wrote the following function for the purpose of reusability:

```
template<typename T>
bool contains(vector<T> v, T x)
{
      if (v.empty())
           return false;
      if (find(v.begin(), v.end(), x) != v.end())
           return true;
      else
           return false;
}
```

Is this the correct way to do, oor is there any better (or more efficient) way?

Comment: Too verbose. I would simply say `return find(v.begin(), v.end(), x) != v.end();`. I would pass the parameters by `const` reference too. You don't need copies.

Comment: The `contains` function here can't be too generic for each `STL Container` since the arguments to `find` algorithm varies differently.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
template<class C, class T>
auto contains(const C& v, const T& x)
-> decltype(end(v), true)
{
    return end(v) != std::find(begin(v), end(v), x);
}
```

Changes:

- Removed the superfluous check for emptyness.
- Parameterized on the container too, so all containers possible.

  - Removed from consideration if `v` is not a container of some sort.
- Return the condition directly, no need for sticking it into a condition.

Of course, if you do many containment-tests on big containers, using an optimized container with optimized algorithms instead of `vector` might be a good idea, though measure it.

A bit more complicated, but using the container-provided `find()` for best performance where applicable:

```
#include <algorithm>

template<class C, class T>
inline auto contains_impl(const C& c, const T& x, int)
-> decltype(c.find(x), true)
{ return end(c) != c.find(x); }

template<class C, class T>
inline bool contains_impl(const C& v, const T& x, long)
{ return end(v) != std::find(begin(v), end(v), x); }

template<class C, class T>
auto contains(const C& c, const T& x)
-> decltype(end(c), true)
{ return contains_impl(c, x, 0); }
```

Comment: I wonder if this could be improved to not match if `C` is not really a container (i.e. `begin(v)` fails to compile).

Comment: The use of auto and decltype everywhere is a bit OTT.

Comment: @James: using both makes SFINAE easier there though...

Comment: @MattMcNabb: It already is removed from consideration for non-containers, because I used `end(c)` in the return-type deduction `decltype`.

Comment: contains should return an `optional<Iterator>` instead of bool, otherwise it is throwing away the information of were the element is located, which can encourage bad performance and even quadratic complexity in loops.

Comment: @gnzlbg: No, actually not. What you are describing is `find`, the result of which `contains` compares to an end-iterator.

Comment: @Deduplicator the only argument for having a `contains` algorithm is to provide a more ergonomic interface than `find` (we don't _really_ need `contains` since we already have `find`). Returning an `optional` allows `contains` to be used in the same way as if it were returning a `bool`, but it also allows things that cannot be done with `find`, like:  `if(auto p = contains(range, value)) { ... use p here if you want ... } else { ... value is not in rage... }`. In particular with find one cannot branch on the value being in the sequence and have the iterator have local scope within the branch.

Comment: I think we dont need two template `typename`. It can be done with one `typename`.

Comment: This is so essential for clean code it should be part of the language (IMHO) !

Comment: @darth_coder: That would assume you can deduce `T` from `C`. (Un-)Fortunately, the needle need not have the same type as the haystack. That allows for foregoing the need to construct an element just for comparison purposes, which can be anything from irrelevant over a significant saving to making things work at all.

Answer (score 8):

One alternative possibility would be something like:

```
template <class T>
bool contains(std::vector<T> const &v, T const &x) { 
    return ! (v.empty() ||
              std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), x) == v.end());
}
```

As far as more efficient goes, there are a couple of possibilities. If you're doing this very often, you might want to consider using `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` instead. They support what you're asking for much more directly. Another obvious possibility would be to continue to store the data in a vector, but keep the vector sorted so you can do the search with `std::binary_search`.

Right now this is O(N). Using `std::set` or a sorted vector with `std::binary_search` will reduce that to O(log N). `std::unordered_set` can reduce the (expected) complexity to O(1).

Big-O can be deceiving though. Especially if the number of elements involved is small, such things as contiguous allocation can make more difference than the theoretical complexity. For a large enough number of elements, `std::unordered_set` will almost certainly be the fastest of these--but that number of elements may be quite a bit larger than you ever actually use.

Personally, I can't say I really favor parameterizing the container type either. The problem is fairly simple: if (for example) somebody stores the data in an `std::set`, it will still work, but it'll give truly terrible performance. If you're going to support associative containers at all, you want to provide code that does so at least reasonably efficiently (which, in those cases means *not* using `std::find`).

Comment: No need to check if it's empty. `std::find` will return `end` if `begin == end`.

Comment: @Rapptz: true. I'm assuming (perhaps prematurely) that it was intended as an optimization--if the vector is empty a substantial part of the time, checking for empty first can avoid pushing the parameters to call `find`.

Comment: Also, using `std::set` or its unordered counterpart should be done after careful profiling (trading continuous data blocks with small numbers of allocations for node-based ones with many more allocations and indirections.)

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Added an alternative using `container.find` to my solution, that should remove your objection to full generalization.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'd expect `find` to be inlined anyway and the first thing it will do is check `begin != end`

Comment: @user673679: Oops. Thanks. Corrected. When applying De Morgan's theorem, I guess you have to apply it entirely...

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new algorithm `contains()` is just too superfluous. The `find()` algorithm is sufficient and as generic as you can get. The code should just look like this:

```
bool contains = find(anycontainer.begin(), anycontainer.end(), testvalue) != anycontainer.end());
```

Comment: That code sample repeats the container name 3 times. Do you think the following interface looks simpler?
"bool exists = contains(anycontainer, testValue);"

Comment: 97 characters to now if an element is present in a container. I refuse to get used to this.

Comment: This is another reason why I prefer C# over C++. :P